# Upgraded to SoapUI Pro 3.3.2 - Date problem

Tags: groovy, soapui

I upgraded to SoapUI Pro to version 3.3.2 and now I've problem with date format.
When I run this code:

`def startDate = new Date()`

`def logg = startDate.format("HH:mm:ss.S", TimeZone.getTimeZone('CET'))`

This error raises:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.Date.format() is applicable for argument types: (String, sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo) values: [HH:mm:ss.S, sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="CET",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=137,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=CET,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=1,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=1]]] Possible solutions: stream(), toYear(), from(java.time.Instant) error at line: 15

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have access to the `java.time` libraries, which are generally superior to `java.util.Date`. If it's not too much trouble for the rest of your work, I would recommend switching.

If you must use `java.util.Date`, you'll want a SimpleDateFormat:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.S")
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"))
println sdf.format(new Date())

==> 06:01:31.299
```

Using a `ZonedDateTime` from `java.time`:

```
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

i = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("CET"))
println i.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.S"))
println i.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS"))

==> 06:01:31.2
==> 06:01:31.299
```

Note that the `S` pattern in the [`java.time.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) was changed from `millisecond` to `fraction-of-second`

Personally the most legible option is using a `java.time.Instant`:

```
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

println Instant.now()
        .atZone(ZoneId.of("CET"))
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS"))

==> 06:12:22.916
```

Comment: How can I add 1 day to SimpleDayFormatter object?

Comment: One more question, how can I get ISODateTimeFormat? Example: 2020-10-16T11:00:00.000+02:00

Comment: @user3624378 you should ask those as new questions. Note, however, that they'll probably be closed as duplicates because they've already been asked & answered. Which is to say, if you search SO for them you should find some results :)

Comment: Yes offcourse - I've figured it out with 1 day and isoformat. Thanks for your reply :-)